# Is there a similarity measure to compare two segmented linear segments?

Tags: python, computer-vision, geometry, computational-geometry

I am searching for a way to evaluate the similarity between two segmented linear segments.
To make things clear, consider the illustration below:

[image]

Scanline 1 is very similar to the Template (in fact it's the Template segmentation pattern scaled down, so it has the same ratios between every segment pair as the Template).

On the other hand, Scanline 2 is way less similar to the Template.

The most relevant resource I found so far is the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio).
However, using the cross-ratio metric as defined in the link above, we can only compare two linear segments that are segmented into 3 parts.

Any ideas of generalizing this metric or using another one as a metric?

Update: The metric should be scale invariant

Comment: You did not tell us if you expect that measure to be 1) translation invariant, 2) scaling invariant. It could even be 3) elastic. These options make a huge difference.

Comment: Indeed, it should be 2) scaling invariant. Translation plays no important role in my case because of the way I extract the scanlines from my image. However, scale is important because I plan to work on different levels of the image pyramid.

Comment: if it is scale-invariant, try 1) to scale it to same values of min and max. 2) use Mean Square Error for a metric between all points between min and max: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

Comment: "Translation plays no important role in my case because of the way I extract the scanlines from my image." Can you explain ? This seems contradictory with scale invariance.

Comment: The scanline extraction is simply done by keeping the pixel values (0-255) along a line that I draw manually on an image.
Concerning scale, I can uniformly sample the values I kept and scale-down the scanline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the comparison of the scanlines will be done without thresholding the values of the image extracted one in order to avoid the "magic number" of the threshold.
The comparison will be made between:

- a binary template scanline derived from the 3d object's CAD model that shows where there is object and where there is not
- a scanline derived from the image containing values in range [0, 255]

The metric to be used is cross correlation implemented using convolution.

Answer (score 0):

For each labeled segment, you can examine the fraction of the template's length that overlaps with the scanline's using, say, [pyinterval](https://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html). The below is untested.

```
from interval import interval
def normalized_segment_overlap(lt, rt, ls, rs):
    assert rt!=lt, "Right and left endpoint of template interval must be different."

    i = interval[lt,rt] & interval[ls,rs]
    l, r = i.extrema
    return (r-l)/(rt-lt)
```

If you want to do this for multiple segments, you can do

```
from interval import interval
def template_overlap_fraction(lt_list, rt_list, ls_list, rs_list):
    is = []
    iterator = zip(lt_list, rt_list, ls_list, rs_list)
    for lt, rt, ls, rs in iterator:
        i = interval[lt,rt] & interval[ls,rs]
        is.append(i.extrema)
    
    intersection_length = sum([pair.sup - pair.inf for pair in is])
    template_length = sum([rt - lt for lt, rt in zip(lt_list, rt_list)])
        
    return intersection_length / template_length
```